# Convert python script to php for dht22 sensor data reading

Tags: php, python

I would convert this Python code to read DHT22 sensor data in php. I don't know python so I can't convert all functions in the php corrispondent.

The python script is from [here](http://electronics.ozonejunkie.com/2014/12/opening-up-the-usr-htw-wifi-temperature-humidity-sensor/) (I add numpy library because I was an error without it)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket
import numpy

TCP_ADDR = 'MYIP'
TCP_PORT = 8899

PACK_LEN = 11

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.settimeout(30)

s.connect((TCP_ADDR, TCP_PORT))

bytes_data = numpy.zeros(PACK_LEN,int)

str_data = s.recv(PACK_LEN) #this should probably have a timeout
hex_data = str_data.encode('hex')

for n in range(0,PACK_LEN): #convert to array of bytes
    lower = 2*n
    upper = lower + 2
    bytes_data[n] = int(hex_data[lower:upper],16)


humid =  (((bytes_data[6])<<8)+(bytes_data[7]))/10.0
temp =  (((((bytes_data[8])&0x7F)<<8)+(bytes_data[9]))/10.0)

if int(bytes_data[8]) & 0x80: #invert temp if sign bit is set
    temp = -1.0* temp

checksum = (int(sum(bytes_data[0:10])) & 0xFF)+1

if checksum == bytes_data[10]:
    print "T" + str(temp) + " H" + str(humid)
else:
    print "Invalid. :("
```

Comment: it would pretty much look almost the same in PHP. Please post whatever you have tried so far

Comment: I suggest you add a PHP Tag

Comment: Thanks cdarke, I added the PHP tag.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a test in php

```
$fp = fsockopen("192.168.0.12", 8899, $errno, $errstr, 20);

if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {

    fwrite($fp, "\n");
    $code = fread($fp, 26);
    fclose($fp);

    $code = array_shift( unpack('H*', $code) );
    echo $code;
}
```